# Python: IndexError: list index out of range Caeser Cipher

Tags: python

I am trying to create a caeser cipher python code and keep getting IndexError: list index out of range   when I type 'y'.  However there are no problems when I type something like 'hello'.  I am not necessarily looking for a solution but would love an explanation as I really don't understand it.

```
    plaintext=raw_input("Enter message: ")
    convert=plaintext.lower()
    alphabet= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]  
    key=2
    cipher=""

    for i in convert:
        if i in alphabet:
            cipher+=alphabet[(alphabet.index(i)+key%len(alphabet))] 
    print("Your decrypted message is: " +cipher)
```

Comment: Sorry, just to add, I think it is because the code is not wrapping it back to the beginning of alphabet but, I thought the mod function would do this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your `(` `)` here:

```
cipher+=alphabet[(alphabet.index(i)+key)%len(alphabet)]
```

Remember precedence of operators.

You are only applying `%` to key

Comment: Thank you so much -  I thought it would be so much more complicated than that.